# NVD3 Scatter Chart Circle Radius

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, nvd3.js

I was wondering how I can set minimum and maximum radii of the circles in an NVD3 scatter chart.

NVD3 Scatter: http://nvd3.org/ghpages/scatter.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call `.sizeRange([minArea, maxArea])` on your chart object.  Note that "size" is proportional to area, not radius, so you need to use the square of the maximum/minimum radius (adjusted by pi/2 if you want to be precise).

Answer (score 4):

As of 1.7.1, call `.pointRange([minArea,maxArea])` .

Answer (score 2):

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
                .showDistX(true)
                .sizeRange([100, 1000]) /*** Chart Circle Range ****/
                .showDistY(true)
                .color(d3.scale.category10().range());


  chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));
  chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));

  d3.select('#chart svg')
      .datum(data(4,40))
      .transition().duration(500)
      .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
```

[Use this this link](http://nvd3.org/examples/scatter.html)  or apply the above code into this [LINK](http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html)

.sizeRange([minArea, maxArea])

example: .sizeRange([100, 1000])